# php send email to multiple recipients individually

Tags: php, email

I have a problem, I am new in php so I need your help.
I want to send multiple emails via phpmailer but the send must be individual to each email in part.
Bellow is my example. The code is working but send all the emails into the TO field and when the email arrives at the inbox is show that the mail has been sent to multiple recipients.

Emails will come from an html textarea
My ex:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/class.smtp.php';


$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$emailList= $_POST['targets'];
$user = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
$mail->ClearAddresses();
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = ''.$_POST['user'];
$mail->Password = ''.$_POST['pass'];
$mail->SetFrom($user, 'Craig');
$mail->addReplyTo('$user', 'Craig');
$mail->Subject = ''.$_POST['subject'];
$mail->Body = ''.$_POST['message'];
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$maillist = explode("\n", $emailList);

    foreach ($maillist as $emailz) {
        $emailz = str_replace(["\n", "\r"], null, $emailz);
        {
        $mail->addAddress($emailz);
    }
    }


 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo 'Message has been sent to: '.$emailz.'<br>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: Move `$mail->Send()` to your foreach loop to send individual emails.

Comment: thanks John like I said i am biginer in php. Can u show me exactly, please?

Comment: Thank you John for your answer. Is woking!!!!!

Comment: Are you asking your users to type in their gmail passwords?

Comment: NO.... I only send promo emails to my customers and i have 2 gmails from when i send